# Java Maven -> quickls add folder of jars as depencency

Tags: java, maven

my Java Project uses a "/libs" folder containing ~100 .jar files. Almost all of them are not in an official maven repository.

1.) In the moment I manually added to whole folder to the classpath with my Eclipse IDE. That enables to compile and run the App using the Eclipse IDE. But if I want to maven to compile and create jar-with-dependencies, maven of course does not know about the "/libs" folder.

2.) I know that I can add a jar file to my local maven repo with `mvn install:install-file` but this would take a very long time  because I would also have to open every jar and find the whole package name to insert as '-DgroupId' and the Name of the Main Class to add as '-DartifactId'

3.) My Questions:
3.1) Is there an easy way to let maven just include all jars in a folder like I did with my Eclipse IDE? I know that would break the principle of maven that every jar is identified with group and artifact id, but it would be a quick solution.

3.2) If it is not possible to add a folder with jars as a dependency in maven, is there a faster way to add a jar file into a local repo. It would be easier if there is a maven command where groupId and artifactId are automatically discovered by the jar that I do not have to open every jar file and find the Main Class and its classpath

Comment: 100 Jars sounds like a lot - do you really want to do the management of the dependencies manually? Where do the JAR files come from, how are they built? Any chance for putting them into a private repo server and have their inter-dependencies managed there as well?

Comment: Have a look at [maven-assembly](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). It allows to copy a complete folder into the result object

Comment: Use a repository manager and upload those files there (maybe via a script using)... after wards you can use all of them as usual deps... you can create jar-with-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: No.

In the past, I have written a script for that because there is not support in Maven for this.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier in that case to not use maven for the packaging but have a custom script for that?